# Best linear approximation of parabola between 0 and d

Tags: approximation-theory

I am currently thinking about the following problem: given a parabola $f(x) = x^2$, what is the best linear approximation $g(x)$ of $f(x)$ between 0 and some $d > 0$? In my case, best approximation means that the maximum $|g(x) - f(x)|$ between 0 and $d$ is minimized.

Comment: Write your line as $g(x)=ax+b$.  Compute the distance as a function of $a,b$, take the derivative with respect to each, set to $0$...